# Unable to get Samba server to work in Linux Mint 17.1

Tags: linux, linux-mint, samba

There are two folders AFolder and .AFolder which I want to share through a Samba server. I am not able to get it to work.

```
shivanand@Pattanshetti-home /etc/samba $ cat smb.conf
[global]
server string = Shivanand's Shared Files
workgroup = PATTANSHETTI
netbios name = Pattanshetti-home
security = user
encrypt passwords = yes
guest account = nobody
name resolve order = bcast host
include = /etc/samba/smbshared.conf
smb passwd file = /etc/samba/smbpasswd
local master = yes
domain master = yes 
preferred master = yes
domain logons = yes
wins support = yes

shivanand@Pattanshetti-home /etc/samba $ cat smbshared.conf
[AFolder]
comment = Linux File Server Share
path = /media/shivanand/HDD\ Data/DATA/dll/AFolder
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = yes
available = yes
public = no
writable = no
force user = shivanand

[.AFolder]
comment = Linux File Server Share
path = /media/shivanand/HDD\ Data/DATA/dll/.AFolder
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = yes
available = yes
public = no
writable = no
force user = shivanand

shivanand@Pattanshetti-home /etc/samba $ smbclient //192.168.1.101/AFolder
Enter shivanand's password: 
Domain=[PATTANSHETTI] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 4.1.6-Ubuntu]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
shivanand@Pattanshetti-home /etc/samba $ smbclient //192.168.1.101/.AFolder
Enter shivanand's password: 
Domain=[PATTANSHETTI] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 4.1.6-Ubuntu]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

Here is some more info:

- The folder "HDD Data" is an NTFS volume.
- I have already tried restarting smbd, nmdb and samba services.
- The user shivanand is already created and enabled through smbpasswd

Edit: removed `guest ok`, but the error still persists.

What might I be doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong share names.

- In smb.conf, you created shares `encfs_encrypted` and `.encfs_encrypted`...
- ...but with smbclient, you're trying to access shares `AFolder` and `.AFolder`.

Shares are named by their section title in smb.conf, and that's the name you must use when accessing them. So use `smbclient //192.168.1.101/encfs_encrypted`.

---

(Aside: `guest ok` and `public` are synonyms but you've set both to the opposite settings. Also, `force user` is a bad idea.)

Comment: Sorry. I corrected it. It is still not working

Comment: I also removed the `guest ok` and restarted. But no change.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also

- Have a matching user to access the share, set up in the Linux system.  If the user is not intended to log in to Linux, then set it as no login, but you still need the user present.
- Make sure you've added the user trying to access the shares to the Samba Password file using the smbpasswd command

I have a heterogeneous network here, but none of it runs on AD, so in order for a windows user to access shares on a samba box, that user also needs to be added to the Linux system and to the samba authentication system.

I initially discovered this after doing exactly what your doing.  I spent 4 or 5 hours trying to figure it out, then finally the penny dropped and I fixed it in about 30 seconds!

Comment: I have exactly the same user and password for my linux system as the credentials given for samba share.

Comment: Ok, so your system level log in has the same credentials, but did you also add the user using smbpasswd too?  You have to make sure that BOTH are done as the credentials are saved in 2 very different locations.

Comment: Yes. I have a user with smbpwd whose credentials are the same as that of my system user

Comment: ok, so the one last thing to check is to make sure that your samba server is set up for an encrypted connection. I think that by default that's switched on now, but check it to be sure.  Most modern day windows based deploys you can't change it, but the fact remains if windows is unecrypted then so must your linux machine, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing the Domain/Workgroup name to from WORKGROUP to MSHOME and this fixed my network browsing issues with Linux Mint 17.1 (MATE x64).